# When are direct products cancellative for finite algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra, direct-product

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a variety in the sense of universal algebra with the additional stipulation that all algebras within $\mathcal{C}$ are finite. Then we'll say direct products are cancellative for $\mathcal{C}$ if for any $H,J, K \in \mathcal{C}$ we have $H \times K \cong J \times K \Rightarrow H \cong J$.

It's well known that direct products are cancellative for finite groups, however, they're not cancellative for finite quasigroups. Is it known what conditions make direct products necessarily cancellative for a class of finite algebras as described above? Or does anyone know where I could find more information on this subject?

Comment: A variety where all algebras are finite is trivial: all algebras are singletons; otherwise, i.e., if there is an algebra $A$ with more than one element, then $A^{\mathbb N}$ is infinite and it belongs to the variety, since varieties are closed under direct products.

Comment: @amrsa I should have phrased myself more clearly; by $\mathcal {C}$ I mean a class consisting of all the finite algebras within a given variety and excluding all infinite algebras. I am aware that $\mathcal {C}$ itself would not generally constitute a variety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are results of this type summarized in Section 5.7 of

Algebras, Lattices, Varieties, volume 1
R. Mckenzie, G. McNulty, W. Taylor
Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole Mathematics Series, 1987.

For example, Corollary 3 (due to L. Lovasz, 1967) to Theorem 5.23 states that

If $A, B, C$ are finite algebras of the same type and $C$ has a 1-element subuniverse, then $A\times C\cong B\times C$ implies $A\cong B$.

Comment: "Subuniverse" = "subalgebra"?